# Bootstrap toggle button instant outline state

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, toggle

I am using bootstrap 5.0 (the one that can import from inline html)  to create a toggle outline button like below.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-bs-toggle="button" autocomplete="off" aria-pressed="false" >{{mode}} Mode</button>
```

In first click, color change instantly from transparent to fill.
But the issue is, if i click the second time, the toggle button don't instantly change the color from fill to transparent. You have to click elsewhere to let it change back to transparent.

How can I make the color change from fill to transparent instantly after the click instead of the need to click somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

styles.css

```
.btn-check:focus + .btn-outline-dark,
.btn-outline-dark:focus {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.btn-check:focus + .btn,
.btn:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular12-bootstrap-we7r6z)

Comment: Hi, I am using angular and I have entered above code into my component .css file. Nothing changed... Except there are less aura line around the button. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @AkiZukiLenn You need to paste in styles.css, share screenshots of what is wrong and what output you want!

Comment: I have move those code to style.css file. Unfortunately nothing changed. 
On second click, which suppose to turn the button from from fill to transparent. 
After I move the mouse away from the button, the button stay in fill. 
But I want the button turn in transparent right after the mouse hover away from the button.
Instead of now, which the button only turn from fill to transparent after I click some where else that's not the button.